# Trying to update my custom list adapter of listView using notifyDataSetChanged but not working

Tags: java, android, listview

How can I update my listView adapter properly when I add a new file? The listView is feed by a an array. I have read a lot and tried several things but nothing works outs. Am I missing something? notifyDataSetChanged is not working for some reason.

**activity.java**

on create:

```
ListView list2;    
CustomList listAdapter;
String[] ficheros;

final File carpeta = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/cc.openframeworks.androidMultiOFActivitiesExample/files/xml");


    list2=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
    list2.setVisibility(GONE);
    list2.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    ficheros = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    listAdapter =  new CustomList(OFActivityA.this, ficheros,fecha);
    list2.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    listarFicherosPorCarpeta(carpeta);

@Override
protected void onResume() {
   super.onResume();


public void listarFicherosPorCarpeta(final File carpeta) {
   for (final File ficheroEntrada: carpeta.listFiles()) {
         if (ficheroEntrada.isDirectory()) {
               listarFicherosPorCarpeta(ficheroEntrada);
              } else {
                 System.out.println(ficheroEntrada.getName());
                 list.add(ficheroEntrada.getName());
              }
            }
      listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
           }
```

CustomList.java

```
public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    private final Activity context;
    private final String[] ficheros;
    private final String[] fecha;

    public CustomList(Activity context, String[] ficheros, String[] fecha) {
        super(context, R.layout.rowlayout, ficheros);
        this.context = context;
        this.ficheros = ficheros;
        this.fecha = fecha;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, null, true);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.listtext);
        TextView txtFecha = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.fechatxt);
        txtTitle.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#015D99"));
        txtTitle.setHeight(123);
        txtFecha.setText(fecha[position]);
        txtTitle.setText(ficheros[position]);

        return rowView;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`notifyDataSetChanged()` will work if the content in dataset has changed. You are calling it in `onResume()` which might get called before your loop in function has finished. Try changing your function call and add `notifyDataSetChanged()` once your for loop completes.

```
public void listarFicherosPorCarpeta(final File carpeta) {
   for (final File ficheroEntrada: carpeta.listFiles()) {
         if (ficheroEntrada.isDirectory()) {
               listarFicherosPorCarpeta(ficheroEntrada);
              } else {
                 System.out.println(ficheroEntrada.getName());
                 list.add(ficheroEntrada.getName());
         }
   }
   listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //call it here after you have updated your data.
}
```

Comment: Hi! i add the line there but i got this error:
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void cc.openframeworks.androidMultiOFActivitiesExample.CustomList.notifyDataSetChanged()' on a null object reference
   Then i add a boolean an make it true con a button click after the new file was added but the listView still with the same elements and i print the the array and  i can see the new data.

Comment: you are calling `listarFicherosPorCarpeta(carpeta);` before you have set adapter. call the function after this line `list2.setAdapter(listAdapter);`

Comment: Hi!i update the code above. I set listarFicherosPorCarpeta(carpeta);  after the adapter and is not crashing, but now my list view is empty. I update the code maybe my order is wrong but alread try some combinations and same result the list view appear empty. THanks

Comment: Hi @karan you have idea why is the adapter appears empty

Comment: @fullrusian try debugging and check if there are values in your list.

Comment: i already print the elements in the console, the list has values

Comment: check this tutorial first, try converting your code into model class based implementation and check. https://www.journaldev.com/10416/android-listview-with-custom-adapter-example-tutorial

Comment: Okay, i have running the tutorial in my project now how can add fichers arrays to feed the listView? I'm stuck in that part @karan

Comment: i put it in other question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58177488/how-to-populate-list-view-using-array-in-a-custom-adapter-using-model-class

Comment: Hi @karan, I Implement the successfully but still having the same problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58191868/how-to-properly-use-notifydatasetchanged?noredirect=1#comment102764091_58191868